# Skip processing in Pipeline If argument met

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, pipeline

I'm grabbing product info from a site and checking o see if it's in stock and shippable or not.  If it's out of stock o not available to ship then I don't care about adding it to my database.  So, I have the item and it's makes its way to the pipeline and once I see that it's out of stock or doesn't ship I just want to quit processing it in the pipeline and dump everything I have on it and go back to the spider to grab the next item to be processed.  I hope that makes since.  I tried the raise DropItem() but nothing happened.  I checked the DB and when that field is empty it should be skipping it right?  Here's the code.

```
Ships = item['Ships']
Stock = item['InStock']
if "shipping not available" in Ships[0].lower():
    raise DropItem()
if len(Stock) is 0:
    raise DropItem ("Test")
if "instock" not in Stock[0].lower():
    raise DropItem()
```

I've tested the output of the code and it's working correctly as far as the if statement goes.  It's just not working when I get to the THEN part. So, to summarize one of the examples in there, When len(Stock) is 0 then I want to stop processing this particular item and move on to getting and processing the next item.

Comment: Can you add a `print item['InStock'], type(item['InStock']` statement before `len(Stock)` and tell me what you see?

Comment: Yes, ty.  I printed a few things for ya.  Here is that bit of code in the pipeline. `Ships = item['Ships']
        Stock = item['InStock']
        print ("Print item Ships ="), (item['Ships']), type(item['Ships'])
        print ("Print item['InStock'] ="), item['InStock'], type(item['InStock'])
        print ("Print Ships ="), Ships
        print ("Print Stock ="), Stock
        print ("Print Ships[0] ="), Ships[0]
        print ("Print Stock[0] ="), Stock[0]`

Comment: and here is the results i got from that one above `Print item Ships =
Print item['InStock'] =
Print Ships =
Print Stock =
Print Ships[0] =
Print Stock[0] =`

Comment: I also put a bit of print code in the actual spider.`print ("item['InStock'] value from spider"), item['InStock'], type(item['InStock'])
print ("item['Ships'] value from spider"), item['Ships'], type(item['InStock'])` and got this result`item['InStock'] value from spider [u'http://schema.org/InStock'] <type 'list'>
item['Ships'] value from spider [u''] <type 'list'>`

Comment: I'm just looking over the InStock one and some of them are empty and thats ok for me.  If I see the words "instock" in there I want to keep processing it but else (even if it's empty) then I want to skip it. It's not skipping it though and when it gets down to the part where I insert these into a table it's erroring when it gets to this empty value.  If it's skipping like it should then it wouldn't even be getting to this insert into table part of the pipeline.

Comment: When i print it from the spider it has a value but as soon as I go to the pipeline and print it, it's empty

Comment: replace `len(Stocks) is 0` to `len(Stocks) > 0`

Comment: If you think that will help after this issue then I can do that for sure but my thinking is this: I'm not even getting to that bit of code yet.  I get the value of item['InStock'] from the spider and it's fine and there is a legit value.  As soon as I start to process it in the pipeline (before I do anything at all with it) I see what the value is and it's now empty.  The only thing between the spider and the pipeline is putting it in my items.py and the  code for that is a simple `InStock = scrapy.Field()` so where is it getting lost?

Comment: could you also add your Spider's `parse` method in your question? Maybe you don't `return item` in the end of the `parse` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  There was a line of code in there that was messing everything up.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

When that line of code was in my pipeline, I had nothing in my results of my `print`.  I removed that line and it all came together.  Thanks for the suggestions.